# UIButton inside UIVIew not centered in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

I'm actually setting a custom UIView programmatically that will contain several UIButton and this is working fine.
But what I'm trying to do is to center a UIButton inside a sub-custom UIView that I've created programmatically. Here is the code I'm actually using

```
//UIView used as a parent for the blurrEffectView
blurredPowerDown = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
                    blurredPowerDown.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                    //I'm calling this for applying my custom view on top of other application (yes this is jailbreak development but issue is not related at it at all
                    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
                    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 2;
                    [window setHidden:NO];
                    [window setAlpha:1.0];
                    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                    [window addSubview:blurredPowerDown];

                    //Code to get blur depending of what is behind the view
                    blur = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
                    blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blur];
                    blurEffectView.frame = blurredPowerDown.bounds;
                    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                    [blurEffectView setAlpha:0.0];
                    [blurredPowerDown addSubview:blurEffectView];

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

            [blurEffectView setAlpha:1.0];

            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];

                    //This is the view I use to center all the button that I will add (in red on the following picture)
                    centerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
                    [centerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
                    centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

                    [blurEffectView addSubview:centerView];

                    [blurEffectView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blurEffectView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:0.7
                                                       constant:0]];

                    [blurEffectView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blurEffectView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:0.5
                                                       constant:0]];


                    [blurEffectView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blurEffectView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];


                    [blurEffectView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:blurEffectView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];

                    //And this is the button that cause me issue
                    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
                    cancelButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
                    cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2.0f;
                    cancelButton.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
                    cancelButton.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;


                    [centerView addSubview:cancelButton];

                    //Constraints removed as per UditS suggestion
                    [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];

                    [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];


                    [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];


                    [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

Here is the screenshot of what it do

[image]

I really don't understand why my UIButton always stay in the top left (like if it has no placement constraints but I have added them !)

I'm really desperated !

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: If I set cancelButton.center = centerView.center; here is what I get:

[image]

EDIT2: As suggested, I've set cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; but here is the result:

[image]

EDIT3: we advance ^^ thanks to @UditS suggestion (delete the height and width constraints) the button is centered but now the border is very strange

[image]

Comment: for placing in center only write yourButton.center = yourView.center

Comment: Do you need your `cancelButton` to be of same height and width as `centerView`?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I've edited my question with what you've suggested.

Comment: @UditS not, same size as in the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable translation autoresizingMask to constraints for your button:

```
cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

ADDITION: If you want to set width and height of button to 80px, you should replace 2 first constraints for cancelButton on these:

```
[cancelButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:80]];

[cancelButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:nil
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                        multiplier:1.0
                                                          constant:80]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, but please see my EDIT2 in question, it take now the whole subview. I wuld like it to be the same as in the first screenshot

Comment: Ok. Now layout is correct. You wrote, that width and height of button should be equal to width and height of centerView. What's wrong? May be you want to set another width?

Comment: Yes, only 80 px, I'm trying your code and will update the situation as soon as tried !

Comment: My device crash after after attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute and constant:80 :/

Comment: Did you remove this and next?

                  [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:centerView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];

Comment: Yes, double checked and the device crash after adding your constraints and removing the ones with constant:0

Comment: Strange. May you write log here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101917/discussion-between-dmitry-arbuzov-and-synny).

Comment: Regarding the code sample above, instead of [cancelButton addConstraint:... I was adding [centerView addConstraint:... I had corrected this and now the button is centered, rounded and with a 80px size ! Thanks @Dmitry Arbuzov for your help, I'm very grateful ! And thanks everyone also :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with your CenterY constraint, as in your code you are making `cancelButton`'s CenterY Equal to `centerView`'s CenterX.

So in place of

```
                [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:centerView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:0.0]];
```

You should have

```
                [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:centerView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:0.0]];
```

As per your **edit** after setting

```
cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

the button will take full width and height of the `centerView` because you are setting it so through the following constraints

```
                [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:centerView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:0]];

                [centerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:centerView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:0]];
```

Remove these contraints and add contraints for constant height and width of the button.

As per **Edit 3**, try adding width and height constraint to the button.

```
                [cancelButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:80.0]];

                [cancelButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cancelButton
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:80.0]];
```

Comment: Copy/Paste error, in my code it's correct. I'll edit the question

Comment: Try `cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` as suggested by @Dmitry

Comment: Not working as I want as the button take now the whole subview :/

Comment: Oh I've forgotten these constraints... We advance ^^ see my edit3. Now the button as a strange border

Comment: My device crash after after attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute and constant:80 :/

Comment: Oh, Made the same mistake of Copy / Paste. It should be `[cancelButton addConstraint`. Answer updated for future readers.